# Emacs inserts wrong symbol instead tab

Tags: emacs

Instead tab-symbol inserts symbol *3B1 5D0*
I've take this from official documentaion

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command)
```

but this is working wrong (C-q TAB is working well)

Comment: What if you change `(kbd "TAB")` to `(kbd "<tab>")`?

Comment: @Chris no, anyway inserts *3B1 5D0*, not tab-symbol

Comment: What does `C-h k [tab]` give?

Comment: @DrMGC If you were able to solve the problem yourself you might want to consider posting an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) below (and explain in a bit more detail what exactly you did to solve it). That way, you might be able to help others who run into the same problem at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When tab doesn't insert tab -- You can see what tab is binded to with `C-x k TAB`. Then You'll find what mode re-binds it. And after initialising the mode You can set it back:

```
(define-key troube-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") self-insert-command)
```

(or bind it to `indent-for-tab-command`).